# Loop over internal complex container

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, abstraction

Suppose a class like

```
class Foo
    {
    private:
        ANonTrivialContainer bar;
        OtherData baz;
    };
```

The iterators of ANonTrivialContainer are bi-directional. From outside, I want to do stuff with the contents of bar. What is prefferable of

- Providing a beginBar() and a corresponding endBar(), returning iterators for ANonTrivialContainer like the accepted answer of [Allowing access to container objects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110486/allowing-access-to-container-objects-in-c). This will work, but exposes internal details to the caller (since it needs to do explicit calls to the underlaying class).
- Providing a custom iterator that forwards all calls to an internal iterator. beginBar and endBar now returns the custom iterator instead.
- Providing a forEach method that takes a reference to an object of a Callback class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide a `visitBars` generic method, taking a functor as the parameter.

```
template<typename F> void visitBars(F visit) {
  for(auto b: bar)
    visit(b);
}
```